# Add 0.5x0.5 degree grid on drawing of country outline

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

How do I draw a 0.5 degree x 0.5 degree grid over the country map in a MATLAB figure?

The code below gives me a gridded figure but not with 0.5x0.5 degree spacing.

```
borders('Iran Islamic Republic of')
grid on
ax.GridLineStyle = '-';
```

Can anyone tell me how to add 0.5x0.5 grid along x and y-axis to this figure?

[The borders function is taken from the MATLAB File Exchange](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/50390-borders)

Comment: Can you provide the code that generates the figure, as well as a picture of the figure itself?

Comment: Dear @MarkSnyder I don't know what are you talking about. I just paste the above code into Matlab and then the figure (the country) is shown for me. I don't have any other thing. I don't know how to do!

Comment: I see now that `borders` is a function on Matlab File Exchange. It's not a default function.

Comment: When you use 3rd party code, please add a link to it in the question.

Comment: oh, I didn't know that. can you tell me what can I do?
here is the link. sorry I didn't know that. @Daniel
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/50390-borders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xticks() and yticks() functions ([matlab tutorial](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html)). Your code should be something like:

```
borders('Iran Islamic Republic of')
grid on
ax.GridLineStyle = '-';

% Modify the X and Y ticks positions
xticks([44:.5:65]);
yticks([25:.5:40]);
```

This creates ticks every 0.5 degrees (from degree 44 until 65 in x, and from 25 to 40 in y). If the tick labels are overlaping, you can delete some. For example for the x-axis:

```
%Delete some labels, otherwise overcrowded 
xlabels = xticklabels();
for i=2:2:length(xticks())
    xlabels(i)={''};
end
xticklabels(xlabels)
```